# How many extra pellets are fired from a Two Shot Prefix Shotgun?

Tags: fallout-4

I was looking at the [legendary weapon effects wikia page](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Legendary_weapon_effects) and came to the two shot entry. It says that it "fires an additional projectile." I remembered that I recently found a two shot combat shotgun. Does its prefix mean that it fires one more pellet or twice the pellets when compared to a normal combat shotgun?

Answer (score 16):

Well, let's put the speculations aside and test it experimentally!

If we compare two identical stock double-barrel shotgun (With a long barrel) in our inventory, we can see that the predicted damage for the shotgun with Two-Shot is already *twice* the damage of the standard shotgun:

[image: Expected damage comparison]

If we test it point-blank on a gentle Deathclaw, we can observe the real damage difference between the two shots, which is just over 2x:

[image: Live Damage comparison]

The slight difference can be explained by the pellets spread. I tried to reduce it to the maximum by using the Long Barrel mod and having my character placed at the exact same spot, doing a Body shot in VATS

So, in conclusion, Two-Shot will fire *twice the amount of pellets* from a shotgun doing correctly twice the damage.

Comment: The displayed 0 accuracy on the two-shot one is a little disturbing :/

Comment: @Autar Yeah it troubled me to. I double checked yesterday in a weapons workbench and the only difference is really only the Two-Shot mod. No idea why it's impacting the accuracy like that.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault Because reduced accuracy is a property of the two shot legendary mod. I'm have a modified description, but IIRC it is stated in vanilla too (though in less detail).

Comment: @Affine Ah, your're right, on the wiki the description is indeed "Fires an additional projectile. Decrease in accuracy". However going from 34 to 0 is a little intense haha

Comment: After you were done, did you hug the "gentle" Deathclaw and kiss its boo-boo all better?

Comment: @Iszi you know, the game makes you think sometimes. Was it a good conservationist thing of me to return the deathclaw egg to its nest, or could this cause the death of innocents? Only time will tell.

Answer (score 3):

> Does its prefix mean that it fires one more pellet or twice the pellets when compared to a normal combat shotgun?

Per your link to the Wikia:

> The Two shot modifier makes the weapon fire an additional projectile while still using only 1 ammo and at slightly reduced accuracy.

*This means that 2 rounds will be expended. Here are some examples that will help answer your question:*

- If you have 10 pellets from a shotgun cartridge, 20 will be fired instead.
- If you have 1 slug fired from a shotgun, 2 will be fired for 1 trigger pull.
- If the two shot was on a hunting rifle, instead of 1 bullet leaving the barrel, 2 will be sent downrange.

Comment: More specifically what I mean is that, in the quote, its usage of the word "projectile" leaves it ambiguous as to whether it means an additional cartridge or an additional pellet, as both could be considered projectiles. Which is where my confusion is coming from.

Comment: A pellet is not considered a cartridge or bullet. Knowing the cartridge is what is doubled I think that rules out ambiguity.

Answer (score 0):

truth is this. when a two shot is applied to the shotgun, a single bullet is added, and doubling the damage of all bullets, and screwing the spread and accuracy. it is explain why the test results were more than double damage. actually it is 2.25X damage boost if ignore other conditions like accuracy or armor.

Comment: Some proof would be useful.

Answer (score -1):

Despite the most voted answer being that it doubles the amount of pellets, this is incorrect, and the 2-shot version doing more than double damage of the single shot actually supports the truth of how 2-shot works on shotguns and that is this:

A normal shotgun produces 8 pellets, with the damage spread among them evenly. A 2-shot fires a 9th pellet that does the same damage as the other 8. Here is some math to explain why it might do more than double damage in a testing scenario:

Firing with 8 pellets and 6 hit. Your listed damage is 80, so you do 60 damage.

Firing with 8 pellets doing 80 damage and a 9th doing 80 damage, when 7 pellets hit, including the 9th, you do 140 damage, more than twice as much as the first test.

Comment: What sourcing do you have to back this up?

Comment: Fired a shotgun with 2 shot against a wall, 9 pellet marks appear, where only 8 appear with a normal shotgun.

Comment: That sounds like details you should add to your answer, along with pics.  That'd go a long way to help make it verifiable.

Comment: I'm just offering an answer, as I came across this search result by accident. But it's well-known in reddits such as fo76 and fo4 that 2-shot adds 1 pellet.

Comment: There are also other quirks with the two-shot not being boosted by damage bonuses and criticals/sneak-attacks.  I forgot the details, but I never use them due to all the weaknesses.  Instigator or Explosive are my go-to weapons.